# R - ensemble with neural network?

Tags: r, neural-network

This is a small sample of my data.frame

```
    naiveBayesPrediction knnPred5 knnPred10 dectreePrediction logressionPrediction correctClass
1                non-bob        2         2           non-bob    0.687969711847463            1
2                non-bob        2         2           non-bob     0.85851872253358            1
3                non-bob        1         1           non-bob    0.500470892627383            1
4                non-bob        1         1           non-bob     0.77762739066215            1
5                non-bob        1         2           non-bob    0.556431439357365            1
6                non-bob        1         2           non-bob    0.604868385598237            1
7                non-bob        2         2           non-bob    0.554624186182919            1
```

I have factored everything

```
   'data.frame':    505 obs. of  6 variables:
     $ naiveBayesPrediction: Factor w/ 2 levels "bob","non-bob": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ knnPred5            : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 ...
     $ knnPred10           : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
     $ dectreePrediction   : Factor w/ 1 level "non-bob": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ logressionPrediction: Factor w/ 505 levels "0.205412826873861",..: 251 415 48 354 92 145 90 123 28 491 ...
     $ correctClass        : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I then tried to ensemble it using neuralnet

```
ensembleModel <- neuralnet(correctClass ~ naiveBayesPrediction + knnPred5 + knnPred10 + dectreePrediction + logressionPrediction, data=allClassifiers[ensembleTrainSample,])
```

> Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] :    requires numeric/complex
>   matrix/vector arguments

I then tried to put in a matrix

```
m <- model.matrix( correctClass ~ naiveBayesPrediction + knnPred5 + knnPred10 + dectreePrediction + logressionPrediction, data = allClassifiers )
```

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
>   contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

I think it must be something to do with the one feature "decistreePrediction" only having 1 level but it only finds one level out of 2 possible outcomes (bob or non-bob) so I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally renamed your `allClassifiers$dectreePrediction` to all be the same thing (re: [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711067/r-how-to-change-name-of-factor-levels))? Also, I don't think it makes sense to make `$logressionPrediction` a factor, unless you bin it first.

Comment: alexforrence thanks for your reply i do not understand the question, i updated with my decision tree code to see if its any use, if anything else is useful I can show that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `neuralnet` function requires the 'variables' to be `numeric` or `complex` values because it is doing matrix multiplication which requires `numeric` or `complex` arguments.  This is very clear in the error returned:

```
Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

This is also reflected with the following trivial example.

```
mat <- matrix(sample(c(1,0), 9, replace=TRUE), 3)
fmat <- mat
mode(fmat) <- "character"

# no error
mat %*% mat

# error
fmat %*% fmat
Error in fmat %*% fmat : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

As a quick demonstration with the actual function I will use the `infert` dataset which is used as a demo within the package.

```
library(neuralnet)
data(infert)

# error
net.infert <- neuralnet(case~as.factor(parity)+induced+spontaneous, infert)
Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

# no error
net.infert <- neuralnet(case~parity+induced+spontaneous, infert)
```

You can leave `correctClass` as a `factor` because it will be converted to a dummy numeric variable anyway but it may be best to also convert it to the respective binary representation.

My suggestions to you are:

1. Convert your factors to the respective binary representations (i.e. 0's and 1's)
2. Leave `logressionPrediction` as numeric
3. Omit variables that only have 1 value.  Including such variables is completely superfluous as no learning can be accomplished with them.