# Changing NA to a Different Factor in R

Tags: r, na

I have a column in my dataset that is a of factor values. Here is an example dataset:

```
a <- c(1,4,6,3,8)
b <- c("No","Yes","NA", "Maybe", "Yes")
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I'd like to change the NA in column 2 ("b") to "Sometimes". I have tried two different approaches that, in my mind, should work but don't seem to give me the correct output:

```
df[is.na(df$b)] <- "Sometimes"
df[df$b == "NA"] <- "Sometimes"
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `"NA"` isn't a real `NA`, it should be just `NA`

Comment: `df$b[df$b == "NA"] <- "Sometimes"`

Comment: In addition, to what David said, see the answers on this question: [how to change name of factor levels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711067/r-how-to-change-name-of-factor-levels)

Comment: Because of the default setting `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`, the suggestion by @jogo works only after setting `df$b <- as.character(df$b)`. And yes, it is not a "real" NA, those are just the two letters; hence it won't be recognized by `is.na()`.

Comment: Sorry, the NA in my dataset comes out as <NA>. Does that change things? It doesn't seem like a regular NA.

Comment: How do I account for the <NA> then? I converted the column to a factor but jogo's approach still didn't work.

Comment: The form `<NA>` is typical for missing levels. That one is "real", as can be checked with `which(is.na(df$b))`.

Comment: But using df$b[df$b == "<NA>"] <- "Sometimes" wont work in my dataset?

Comment: You need to introduce a new level if you don't want to convert the entries into characters. You could try `levels(df$b) <- c(levels(df$b),"Sometimes");
df$b[is.na(df$b)]<-"Sometimes"`... As I have just noticed, this has been mentioned in the second part of the answer by @fishtank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using "NA" (i.e. character string), then the following will change it to a different factor "Sometimes"

```
> df <- data.frame(a,b)
> levels(df$b)
[1] "Maybe" "NA"    "No"    "Yes"
> levels(df$b)[levels(df$b)=="NA"]
[1] "NA"
> levels(df$b)[levels(df$b)=="NA"]<-"Sometimes"
> df$b
[1] No        Yes       Sometimes Maybe     Yes  
Levels: Maybe Sometimes No Yes
> df
  a         b
1 1        No
2 4       Yes
3 6 Sometimes
4 3     Maybe
5 8       Yes
```

Otherwise, if you had use `NA`, this will add `Sometimes` as a new factor and use `is.na` to change it:

```
b <- c("No","Yes",NA, "Maybe", "Yes")
df<-data.frame(a,b)
levels(df$b)<-c(levels(df$b),"Sometimes") # introduce a new factor
df[is.na(df$b),"b"]<-"Sometimes"

> df
  a         b
1 1        No
2 4       Yes
3 6 Sometimes
4 3     Maybe
5 8       Yes
```