# Classification - Usage of factor levels

Tags: r, classification, prediction

I am currently working on a predictive model for a churn problem. 
Whenever I try to run the following model, I get this error: At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name. This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to X0, X1. Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names.

```
fivestats <- function(...) c( twoClassSummary(...), defaultSummary(...))
fitControl.default    <- trainControl( 
    method  = "repeatedcv"
  , number  = 10
  , repeats = 1 
  , verboseIter = TRUE
  , summaryFunction  = fivestats
  , classProbs = TRUE
  , allowParallel = TRUE)
set.seed(1984)

rpartGrid             <-  expand.grid(cp = seq(from = 0, to = 0.1, by = 0.001))
rparttree.fit.roc <- train( 
    churn ~ .
  , data      = training.dt  
  , method    = "rpart"
  , trControl = fitControl.default
  , tuneGrid  = rpartGrid
  , metric = 'ROC'
  , maximize = TRUE
)
```

In the attached picture you see my data, I already transformed some data from chr to factor variable.

[image: DATA OVERVIEW]

I do not get what my problem is, if I would transform the entire data into factors, then for instance the variable total_airtime_out will probably have around 9000 factors.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Can you please add dummy data or a sample + the code (incl. packages) with which one can recreate your error message? Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

It's not exactly possible for me to reproduce your error, but my educated guess is that the error message tells you everything you need to know:

> **At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name.** This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to X0, X1. **Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names.**

Emphasis mine. Looking at your response variable, its levels are `"0"` and `"1"`, these aren't valid variable names in R (you can't do `0 <- "my value"`). Presumably this problem will go away if you rename the levels of the response variable with something like

`levels(training.dt$churn) <- c("first_class", "second_class")`

as per [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711067/r-how-to-change-name-of-factor-levels).

Answer (score 8):

How about this base function:

```
 make.names(churn) ~ .,
```

to "make syntactically valid names out of character vectors"?

[Source](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the correct answer of @einar, here's the dplyr syntax of converting the factor levels:

```
training.dt  %>% 
  mutate(churn = factor(churn, 
          levels = make.names(levels(churn))))
```

I slightly prefer to change only the *labels* of the factor levels, as the levels change the underlying data, like this:

```
training.dt  %>% 
  mutate(churn = factor(churn, 
          labels = make.names(levels(churn))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by setting `classProbs = FALSE` in the `trainControl()` this solved the issue and kept the level `0` and `1`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem,

```
class(iris$Species); levels(iris$Species)
iris.lvls <- factor(iris, levels = c("1", "2", "3"))
class(iris.lvls); levels(iris.lvls)
```